# For loop overwriting text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, typescript

My array called `myEmployees` has 5 names in it, yet when I run the code it only prints out 3 of them. I believe this is happening because the `for` loop in the script is overwriting the previous line that it wrote in the HTML document. How can I fix this?

> Yearly Bulletin Board Announcements!
>
> Congratulations to Taylor, you have been here for 9 years and you meet the magic number! You get 2 extra weeks of PTO!
>
> Derek, thank you for your service over the past 8 years. I look forward to many more years working with you!
>
> Tyler, no longer works here.

The above  is what shows on my screen when I run the code, there should be two other statements to appear. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
<body>

  <h1>Yearly Buttetin Board Announcements!</h1>
  <h2 id='win'></h2>
  <h3 id='here'></h3>
  <h4 id='notHere'></h4>

  <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
```

TypeScript

```
for( i = 0; i < myEmployees.length; i++ ) {
    const employee = myEmployees[i];
    let magicNumber   = employee.extraVacay;
    let stillEmployed = employee.stillEmployed;
    let timeInJob     = employee.timeInJob;
    let name          = employee.name;

    if( magicNumber > 30 && timeInJob > 5 && stillEmployed == true ) {

        document.getElementById('win').innerHTML = (`Congratulations to ${name}, you have been here for ${timeInJob} years and you meet the magic number! You get 2 extra weeks of PTO!`);

    }
    else if (stillEmployed == true) {

        document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = (`${name}, thank you for your service over the past ${timeInJob} years. I look forward to many more years working with you!`);

    }
    else {

        document.getElementById('notHere').innerHTML = (`${name}, no longer works here.`)
    }
};
```

Comment: Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when setting only text, as it's faster (no HTML parsing and hidden DOM manipulation) but also secure as it prevents HTML injection (XSS, etc).

Comment: You are using ".innerHTML =" and this will overwrite the last thing you set, so you will never get more than 3 lines with the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct-- `innerHTML` is overwriting the previous value-- use `+=` instead:

```
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML += (`${name}, thank you for your service over the past ${timeInJob} years. I look forward to many more years working with you!`);
```

Comment: This solved it, thank you! It has me moving in the right direction now.

Comment: @bemon -- you're welcome! Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed overwriting what you inserted in earlier. Instead of using a series of header tags, I would use an `<ol>` tag for 'win,' 'here,' and 'notHere', and append elements from the array when they meet the necessary conditions.

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of that...great idea for next for me to keep that in mind. I have done that before so now that you mention it I am surprised I didn't think of that route.

Answer (score 1):

The below statement is overriding the existing HTML.

```
 document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = (`${name}, thank you for your service over the past ${timeInJob} years. I look forward to many more years working with you!`);
```

You have to append the previous value to the new text. Updated code should look something like below

```
var prevText =  document.getElementById('here').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = prevText + (`${name}, thank you for your service over the past ${timeInJob} years. I look forward to many more years working with you!`);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```
document.getElementById('here').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'your html')
```

It can have [better performance](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/insertadjacenthtml-enables-faster-html-snippet-injection/) than using innerHTML, especially when using `beforeend`.