# How to print javascript while loop result in html textarea?

Tags: javascript

Prints '2 x 10 = 20' but not the whole table  when the input is 2. I tried various means. But the result is same.

No error. Just like to print the whole multiplication table.

```js
function loop() {
  var i = 1;
  var x = document.getElementById("num").value;

  //document.getElementById("result").value = result;

  while (i <= 10) {

    document.getElementById("result").value = x + " x " + i + " = " + i * x;
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>While loop: </h1>
<p>The while loop keeps repeating an action until an associated condition returns false.</p>
<img src="images/loop.jpg" /><br/>
<img src="images/loop2.jpg" /><br/>

<body>
  <p>JavaScripts Runs:</p>
  <script src="while_1loop.js">
  </script><br/> What number table would you like to have?<input type="number" name="" id="num" /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="loop()" ;>Start</button><br>
  <textarea rows="12" cols="15" id="result" readonly>
       
              </textarea><br/>
```

[image]

Comment: Friends, I see the loop function is from the source while_2loop.js. :)

Comment: `document.getElementById("result").value += x + " x " + i + " = " + (i * x)+"\n";`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop overwriting text in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083750/for-loop-overwriting-text-in-html)

Comment: The dupe is not obviously the same since we have value here and not innerText

Comment: Sure but it is still a dupe, if that's an issue they can look at [Javascript: filling inputs with text without overwriting the text that is already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935862/javascript-filling-inputs-with-text-without-overwriting-the-text-that-is-alread)

Comment: Thanks for the response: I missed the increment '+' in document.getElementById("result").value =, it should be document.getElementById("result").value +=. Well it's done!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are always changing the value of 'result' rather than adding to it:

```js
function loop() {
  var i = 1;
  var x = document.getElementById("num").value;

  //document.getElementById("result").value = result;

  while (i <= 10) {

    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    var sum = document.createTextNode(x + " x " + i + " = " + i * x + "\n");

    result.appendChild(sum);
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>While loop: </h1>
<p>The while loop keeps repeating an action until an associated condition returns false.</p>
<img src="images/loop.jpg" /><br/>
<img src="images/loop2.jpg" /><br/>

<body>
  <p>JavaScripts Runs:</p>
  <script src="while_1loop.js">
  </script><br/> What number table would you like to have?<input type="number" name="" id="num" /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="loop()" ;>Start</button><br>
  <textarea rows="12" cols="15" id="result" readonly>
       
              </textarea><br/>
```

Comment: Already answered in the comment. Please vote to close  - and at least cache the paragraph instead of having it inside the loop

Comment: When adding a comment it says "Avoid answering the question in the comments" - you should add an answer instead. The comment was not there when I started writing the answer anyway. I was also fixing the problem the person had, rather than optimising it!

Comment: @mplungjan Well that was foolish, as a gold javascript badge holder you should've hammered it as one of the several dupes

Comment: I get that now. I wanted op to delete instead

Comment: Yeah :( If only life were that easy

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you mean,

You rewrite whole textarea with this code:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = x + " x " + i + " = " + i * x;
```

but you need add new result after older results. Something like this:

```
var oldValue = document.getElementById("result").value;
var result = x + " x " + i + " = " + i * x;
document.getElementById("result").value = oldValue + '\n' + result;
```